# Equivalence of Cartesian product of 3 sets with parentheses

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Say I have three sets.
$A = \{1,2\},
B = \{3,4\},
C = \{5,6,7\}$.

Would the following set equivalence statement be true?

$(A \times B) \times C = A \times (B \times C)$

I know that $A \times B \times C$ would have a cardinality of $12$ and the values would be:
$S = \{(1,3,5), (1,3,6), (1,3,7), (1,4,5), (1,4,6), (1,4,7), (2,3,5), (2,3,6),\\
(2,3,7), (2,4,5), (2,4,6), (2,4,7)\}$

In the set equivalence statement would the parenthesis change anything about the way in which the resulting set is formed?

Answer (score 1):

To be precise, there's an obvious isomorphism between the two sets.  That's because technically, there's no such thing as an ordered triple.  What we think of an an ordered triple is actually an ordered pair, one element of which is itself an ordered pair.  So, for example, one element of your first set is $((1, 3), 5)$, whereas the equivalent element of your second set is $(1, (3, 5))$.

So it's not quite correct to say that the two sets are equal.  However, there's an obvious mapping between the two sets that preserves pretty much any property that you're likely to be interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the Cartesian product is neither commutative nor associative. To cite a simpler example from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Non-commutativity_and_non-associativity),

$$A:=\{1\},\\
(A\times A)\times A=\{((1,1),1)\}\neq \{(1,(1,1))\}= A\times (A\times A)$$